# Using long and arrays in C++

Tags: c++, binary, converters

I've been working on a program that converts numbers into binary. As you can see my program [here](http://pastie.org/1356965), I've written so that it can scale for larger numbers then a traditional binary code, such as 2 lines (16-bits) for numbers bigger then 255. However, going larger requires long instead of int, but that doesn't seem to be playing well, producing output such as [this](http://pastie.org/1356983). Would anyone mind helping me change the program to use long? Or would it require a fundamental change in the code instead of some minor edits?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int j=0;
    int c=8;
    long a = 1;
    int i=1;
    cin >> a;
    while (a >= (pow(2,c))) {
        c = c+8;
        i++;
        }
    long block[i*8];
    for (long tw;tw<(i*8);tw++)
    {
        block[tw] = 0;
    }
    j=((i*8)-1);
    long b = 0;
    while (j != -1)
    {
        if (b+(pow(2,j))<=a)
        {
            block[j]=1;
            b=b+(pow(2,j));
        }

        j--;
    }
    long q=0;
    cout << endl;
    int y=1;
    long z = 0;
    for (y;y<=i;y++) {
        for (z;z<8;z++) {
            cout << block[z+q];
        }
        cout << endl;
        z = 0;
        q = q + (8*y);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just curious, witch was your first programming language?

Comment: Technically TI-Basic, but mostly C++

Comment: Is this a hw question? What's the input look like and what's the output suppose to look like?
The coding style looks inconsistent and terrible btw.

Comment: I am surprised this line compiles:

`long block[i*8];`

Comment: @Cashcow - in strict C++ it would not, but most likely this is being compiled in GCC-g++, which has VLAs as an extension to C++.

Comment: No, it's something I wrote up in my spare time today. Input should be a single number, output would be something like http://pastie.org/1357043. Yes I know it's terrible, I wrote up the entire thing in about 10 minutes

Comment: @CashCow: It's Variable Length Array. Nothing else than syntactic sugar for `alloca()`

Comment: @CashCow: IIRC, g++ will compile that without as much as throwing a warning. Something I learned when I moved from g++ to VC++ once.

Comment: @galileo it doesn't look like that example's working. The binary representation for 17 is 0001 0001 in dec and 0001 0111 in hex. Neither of them match 1000 1000.

Comment: <math.c> is a C header. In C++ you should use <math> header, to put all functions in std namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making your code far more complicated than it needs to be.  This will print out a single 32-bit integer in binary:

```
const unsigned int bit_count = sizeof(int) * 8 - 1;

int a;
std::cin >> a;

for (unsigned int i = bit_count; i > 0; --i)
{
    unsigned int t = (1 << i);
    std::cout << (a & t ? "1" : "0");
}
std::cout << (a & 1 ? "1" : "0");
std::cout << std::endl;
```

If you want to block it off by ranges to make it easier to read, you simply need to place range on the loop (or move it to a function that takes a range).

Answer (score 0):

Why not something simple like this? You could store the intermediate bits in an array or a string instead of using cout.

```
int convert(long n)
{
   long k=1;
   while(k<n)//find the most significant bit
   {
      k*=2;
   }
   if(k>n)//fix the overshoot
   {
      k/=2;
   }

 while(k>0)
 {
    if(int(n/k)%2==0)
    {
       cout<<0;//find the (next) most 
    }
    else 
    {
       cout<<1;//significant binary digit
    }
    k/=2;//go to the next column to the right and repeat
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a bit more flexibly, here's another way to do it with templates. Template instantiations with signed types are omitted intentionally due to extension issues.

```
template <typename T>
void print_binary(const T input, const short grouping = 4)
{
    unsigned int bit_count = sizeof(T) * 8;
    T nth_bit = 1 << (bit_count - 1);

    for(int i = 0; i < bit_count; i++, nth_bit >>= 1 )
    {
        cout << (input & nth_bit ? "1" : "0");
        if( i % grouping == grouping-1 ) // print binary in groups
            cout << ' ';
    }

    cout << endl;
}

template <>
void print_binary<signed>(const signed input, const short grouping);
template <>
void print_binary<signed short>(const signed short input, const short grouping);
template <>
void print_binary<signed long>(const signed long input, const short grouping);
template <>
void print_binary<signed char>(const signed char input, const short grouping);
```